# select group by in sql multiple columns

Tags: sql, select

I have three columns in one table (code, code alt and product). Code column has duplicate data. I want to leave all results without repeating the code column. I try with this

```
 Select code, code alt, product from table
 where code in 
  (
     select code from table
     group by code 
     having count (code)=1
     )
```

but do not appear all results.

Thanks

Comment: cab you provide some sample data with the expected result?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to leave only one row with the particular code from the bunch of rows with the same code you need to decide which one from multiple rows you want to leave.

You need some criteria by which you will be able to rank rows with the same code and select one from them by higher (for example) rank value. The script below will leave only one - random - row with specific code.

This is just an example that shows you the idea and it intended for SQL Server - because you do not pointed your DBMS

```
with [src] as (
    select code, [code alt], product, rank() over(partition by code order by newid()) [rank]
    from [table])
select * from [src] where [rank] = 1
```

[Ranking Functions](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189798.aspx)